# Objects duplicate strangely when joined

Tags: mesh, objects, transforms

I am trying to join together a mesh of a cup and many small mesh objects inside the cup using `Ctrl+J`. For some reason, along with joining the objects together, this is producing a strange combination of duplication, rotation, and translation. Any ideas about the cause or for a solution? Thanks for your help!

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using a Subdivision surface modifier on the cup and a mirror modifier on some of the interior objects? Ctrl J merges the objects data, but only keeps the modifier of the active object. You may have to apply the modifiers of the objects to be merged first.

Comment: @Leander I was using those modifiers. I just fixed the problem by selecting all the objects, using 'Alt+C' to apply convert to mesh and effectively apply the modifiers. Then the join worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Add an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using unapplied modifiers on the objects. To apply the modifiers to so many objects, I used the command <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> while having all the objects selected. Then used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to join like normal.